# Confluent Platform: Schema Registry Subjects

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

Working with Confluent Platform, the platform offered by the creators of Apache Kafka, and I have a question:

In the documentation of the [Schema Registry API Reference](http://confluent.io/docs/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html#subjects), they mention the abstraction of a "Subject".  You register a schema under a "subject" which is of the form **topicName-key**, or **topicName-value**, yet there is no explanation as to why you need (as it implies) a *separate* schema for the key and value of messages on a given topic.  Nor is there any direct statement to the effect that registration with a "subject" necessarily associates the schema with that topic, other than mnemonically.

Further confusing matters, the subsequent examples ("get schema version for subject" and "register new schema under subject") on that page *do not* use that format for the subject name, and instead use just a topic name for the "subject" value.  If anyone has any insight into a) why there are these two "subjects" per topic, and b) what the proper usage is, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Confluent Schema Registry is actually a bit inconsistent with subject names :)

Indeed, the `KafkaAvroSerializer` (used for new Kafka 0.8.2 producer) uses `topic-key|value` pattern for subjects ([link](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroSerializer.java#L62-L66)) whereas `KafkaAvroEncoder` (for old producer) uses `schema.getName()-value` pattern ([link](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroEncoder.java#L58)).

The reason why one would have 2 different subjects per topic (one for key, one for value) is pretty simple:

say I have an Avro schema representing a log entry, and each log entry has a source information attached to it:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"LogEntry",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"line",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"source",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"SourceInfo",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"host",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"...",
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

A common use case would be that I want to partition entries by source, thus would like to have two subjects associated for topic (and subjects are basically revisions of Avro schemas) - one for key (which is `SourceInfo`) and one for value (`LogEntry`).

Having these two subjects would allow partitioning and storing the data as long as I have a schema registry running and my producers/consumers can talk to it. Any modifications to these schemas would be reflected in the schema registry and as long as they satisfy compatibility settings everything should just serialize/deserialize without you having to care about this.

**Note:** any further information is just *my personal thoughts* and maybe I just don't yet fully understand how this is supposed to work so I might be wrong.

I actually like more how the `KafkaAvroEncoder` is implemented rather than the `KafkaAvroSerializer`. `KafkaAvroEncoder` does not in any way enforce you to use ONE schema per topic key\value whereas `KafkaAvroSerializer` does. This might be an issue when you plan to produce data for multiple Avro schemas into one topic. In this case `KafkaAvroSerializer` would try to update the `topic-key` and `topic-value` subjects and 99% would break if compatibility is violated (and if you have multiple Avro schemas they are almost always different and incompatible with each other).

On the other side, `KafkaAvroEncoder` cares just about schema names and you may safely produce data for multiple Avro schemas into one topic and everything should work just fine (you will have as many subjects as schemas).

This inconsistency is still unclear to me and I hope Confluent guys can explain this if they see this question/answer.

Hope that helps you

Comment: The idea is that you should always want to use the `KafkaAvroSerializer` to ensure the serializer, validates & registers schemas and you follow the schema evolution capabilities.
In other words - you should never `plan to produce data for multiple Avro schemas into one topic` - and if you do so - you do it on your own risk - without using the schema registry

Comment: So, Antonios. How do you propose to have schema evolution, multiple types of events, AND order all maintained?